# query for selecting different recent records with different categoryid

Tags: mysql

I have following db structure in mysql.

Table: Story

```
Id Name categoryid date
1  Pa   4          2011-03-22 09:56:15
2  Pb   1          2011-03-23 09:56:16
3  Pc   2          2011-03-24 09:56:17
4  Pd   3          2011-03-25 09:56:18
5  Pe   1          2011-03-26 09:56:19
6  Pf   2          2011-03-27 09:56:20
7  Pg   3          2011-03-28 09:56:22
8  Ph   1          2011-03-29 09:56:23
```

I want to select results in a way so that it should select only 4 records, 1 for each categoryid.

I need to show result as below, latest record from each category.

```
Id Name categoryid date
8  Ph   1          2011-03-29 09:56:23
6  Pf   2          2011-03-27 09:56:20
7  Pg   3          2011-03-28 09:56:22
1  Pa   4          2011-03-22 09:56:15
```

Is it possible, please help me to make this query.

Comment: What is the criteria for the statement? Without knowing that it could be as simple as select where ID in (8,6,7,1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM categories 
 WHERE (categoryid, date) IN 
       (
        SELECT categoryid, MAX(date)
          FROM categories
          GROUP BY categoryid
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from categories as t1
inner join (
select categoryid,max(date) as date
from categories
group by categoryid) as t2
on t1.categoryid = t2.categoryid and t1.date = t2.date


alter table categories add index i (categoryid,date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Name, categoryid, date FROM story GROUP BY categoryid ORDER BY date
```